# FFmpeg compose, multi layers and filters

Tags: video, ffmpeg, blending, webm

Pretty new to FFmpeg. We would like to use FFmpeg as a important part of an AR project.

Currently, we find it is not easy for us.

We want to compose the footages with FFmpeg.

We got 5 layers, wanted to blend them with specific mode, like the things in After Effects.

- layer-1/ [A.webm] video，vp9 codec, which has a transparent BG,has to be added as [normal mode]
- layer-2/ [B.mp4] video, optical-flare things with black BG,has to be added as [screen mode]
- layer-3/ [C.mp4] video, some motion graphic things with light BG,has to be added as [overlay mode]
- layer-4/ [BG.MP4], backgound things, has to be added as [normal mode]

After we blend those 4 (like pre-compose,use blend filter), we want to add another layer-5/[icon.png] which is the special icon.

Layer-5 need to overlay the pre-compose. We have to overlay it at the special position (use overlay filter?).

Cause [icon.png] may change frequently. we want to deal with that after the 4 layer blending.

But at the first step, when we set normal mode for layer-1 in blend filter, layer-1 [A.webm] lost the transparent BG，it gave us a black BG which block all other things.
Blend filter can not handle the alpha channel of vp9 webm?
When we set the mode of layer-1 to screen mode,the translucent thing was not what we need.

Could you please give us some commands to achieve the blend above?

The commands that really work will be extremely useful for our FFmpeg initiation.

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i transparent.webm -i bg.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]format=yuva420p [a]; [1:v]format=yuv420p [b]; [a][b]blend=all_mode='normal':shortest=1:all_opacity=1,format=yuv420p" output.mp4 >log
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7f8876008600] v1.8.0
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'transparent.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Chrome
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuva420p(tv), 640x360, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      alpha_mode      : 1
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'bg.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 728 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 725 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7f8877806600] v1.8.0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (libvpx-vp9) -> format
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> format
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x7f8877806600] v1.8.0
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  239 fps=113 q=-1.0 Lsize=     232kB time=00:00:03.93 bitrate= 482.5kbits/s dup=1 drop=2 speed=1.86x
video:228kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.586669%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.55  size:  5385
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] frame P:62    Avg QP:24.42  size:  2373
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] frame B:176   Avg QP:31.31  size:   456
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.8%  2.5% 95.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] mb I  I16..4: 18.6% 68.4% 13.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] mb P  I16..4:  1.6%  4.0%  0.7%  P16..4: 14.8%  7.0%  4.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:67.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 17.4%  2.5%  0.4%  direct: 0.5%  skip:78.9%  L0:53.1% L1:40.4% BI: 6.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] 8x8 transform intra:60.1% inter:60.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 16.6% 27.4% 10.7% inter: 3.0% 2.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] i16 v,h,dc,p: 56% 37%  6%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 40%  6% 48%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 35% 22% 23%  3%  3%  4%  3%  4%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 20% 21%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] ref P L0: 69.3% 12.8% 13.6%  4.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] ref B L0: 92.9%  5.9%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] ref B L1: 96.1%  3.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f8877817200] kb/s:467.59
```

Comment: Share full log of your attempt.

Comment: `ffmpeg -c:v libvpx-vp9 -i transparent.webm -i bg.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]format=yuva420p [a]; [1:v]format=yuv420p [b]; [a][b]blend=all_mode='normal':shortest=1:all_opacity=1,format=yuv420p" output.mp4`        We just simply try this command to add a transparent webm onto the bg.mp4, the composite has been done with the command. But the transparent webm lost the alpha channel, webm becomes a video with black bg that block the under-layer bg.mp4.  vp9 webm not supported？ For other layers，we do not even know how to combine them in one command. Could you please give us a example？Thanks~ @Gyan

Comment: We just updated the question,added what we have done. Hope for your kindly help~ Grateful thanks~@Gyan

Comment: Will look at it tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks a lot~ If we use overlay, it turns to be ok. We hope [blend=all_mode='normal'] could be the same as [overlay]. But it looks like only overlay can handle the alpha channel of vp9 webm. Layers being blended(composite) and then letting subtitles and logs overlay on the it, that way makes things  clear. So we firstly use blend mode instead of using overlay.It will be our honor to have your command that can achieve the blend and overlay we metioned in the question. Grateful thanks~ @Gyan